# Java return indexof array based x y

Tags: java, android, arrays

I got a method that is like below

```
    private double get_date_number(String day, String month, String year) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        date_array[0][0] = 6.18;
        date_array[0][1] = 1.22;
        date_array[0][2] = 6.26;
        date_array[0][3] = 6.30;
        return date_array[Integer.parseInt(month)-1][Integer.parseInt(day)-1];
    }
```

and I'm calling it like below:

```
        date_number = get_date_number(Day, Month, Year);
```

date_array is defined as double[][]

date_number is defined as double

If I return:

```
return date_array[0][2];
```

It works like a charm but if I do it like above the app crashes...

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What does "the app crashes" mean? Do you get an exception? Post the exact error message, including the stack trace.

Comment: Also: what are the values in `month` and `day`?

Comment: 09-24 11:18:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 11:18:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(416): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
09-24 11:18:43.552: E/AndroidRuntime(416):  at com.antmoves.stardome.gr.find_horoscope.get_date_number(find_horoscope.java:443)

These are written in my LogCat....

Comment: Is the syntax right... This shoud me working or not?

Comment: What are the Values that u are passing ??

Comment: Then either your input is wrong, (either month is bigger than 1, or day is bigger than 4), or your array is not instantiated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds of your 2D array `date_array` has been exceeded. This more than likely is happening in the line that contains either :

```
date_array[0][3] = 6.30;
```

or

```
date_array[Integer.parseInt(month)-1][Integer.parseInt(day)-1]
```

Check the values for `month` and `day` and ensure that you have enough rows and columns respectively to match these.

Comment: I was calling the class with wrong numbers and they were out of bounds... Thanks for your help...